# SVN commit fails with permission denied using svnserve

Tags: svn, permissions

I have seen a lot of this issue on stack but the fix seems to generally be related to serving a remote svn server with apache.  I'm serving mine using svnserve.

I'm able to check out an svn repository using

```
%svn checkout svn://my.url.com/test --username justin
```

and then entering the password.  I followed [these](http://odyniec.net/articles/ubuntu-subversion-server/) directions for permissions and [these](http://programster.blogspot.co.uk/2013/09/ubuntu-12-set-up-svn-server.html) directions for setting up and running the server.

When I try to add a simple test.txt file and commit I get the following error:

```
svn commit -m "Modified test.txt"
Adding         test.txt
Transmitting file data .svn: E000013: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: E000013: Can't open file '/home/svn/test/db/txn-current-lock': Permission denied
```

I think the permissions for the user are somehow incorrect, but I'm unsure of how to fix them.  The repositories are at /home/svn on my remote machine.

Comment: So thanck you! I had same problem, because on Suse131 systemd service svnserve have user/group svn:svn on execution, but folder with my repo have root owner. It's two ways to resolve: chown repo's folder to svn, or change user which execute svnserve to root in config of svnserve.service.

Answer (score 2):

It is a permissions problem, but be careful it seems to have some non regular files too. I fixed like this:

Go to the svn path where repositories are kept and then correct the
permissions like this:

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 666 {} \;
find . -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
```

Note: if the user using the svn belongs to the group owning the files, then the last digit of the respective permissions can be set to 0, eg: 770.